# SQL Query to provide a count of rows on sales order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping you can help.

We have an app that displays a grid. We can add custom fields to the grid using subqueries with which I am struggling. The main grid query looks like this.

```
SELECT TOP 300000
'' AS alloc_status
,'' AS stock_status
,wo_description
,wo_quantity
,wo_number
,wo_pwos_id
,vad_variant_code
,oh_order_number
,oh_datetime
,ohd_dm_id
,ohd_customer_name
,vad_description AS vad_description_Condition
,vad_variant_code AS vad_variant_code_Condition
,wo_id AS key_id
FROM works_order
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_analysis
ON works_order_analysis.woa_wo_id = works_order.wo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process
ON works_order_process.wop_id = works_order.wo_current_wop_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process_analysis
ON works_order_process_analysis.wopa_wop_id = works_order_process.wop_id
INNER JOIN variant_detail
ON variant_detail.vad_id = works_order.wo_vad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_total
ON works_order.wo_id = works_order_total.wot_wo_id
LEFT JOIN order_line_item
ON oli_id = wo_oli_id
LEFT JOIN order_header
ON oh_id = oli_oh_id
LEFT JOIN job_number
ON jn_id = wo_jn_id
LEFT JOIN works_order_process_subcontract_analysis
ON wopsa_wop_id = wop_id
LEFT JOIN order_header_detail
ON ohd_oh_id = oh_id
LEFT JOIN customer_detail
ON cd_id = oh_cd_id
WHERE ((cd_ow_account = 'NOTHS')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'EBAY')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = '4008')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'TRUSCA')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1))
AND ((wo_required_datetime <= '2016-12-24 23:59:59'
OR wo_required_datetime IS NULL)
AND (wo_wos_id <> 4)
AND (wo_kit = 0))
```

The subquery is to basically provide a column that looks at the sales order and returns a count of row within that order. When I do this I get the following:

There was a problem retrieving the data:
subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, < etc
or when the subquery is used as an expression

Below is the query complete with subquery. If anyone can help that would be amazing

```
SELECT TOP 300000
'' AS alloc_status
,'' AS stock_status
,wo_description
,wo_quantity
,wo_number
,wo_pwos_id
,vad_variant_code
,oh_order_number
,oh_datetime
,ohd_dm_id
,ohd_customer_name
,(SELECT
COUNT(order_line_item.oli_id) AS 'Count'
FROM dbo.order_line_item
INNER JOIN dbo.order_header
ON order_line_item.oli_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_detail
ON order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_setting
ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
WHERE variant_setting.vas_manufactured_variant = 1
GROUP BY order_header.oh_order_number)
AS CustomLineCount
,vad_description AS vad_description_Condition
,vad_variant_code AS vad_variant_code_Condition
,wo_id AS key_id
FROM works_order
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_analysis
ON works_order_analysis.woa_wo_id = works_order.wo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process
ON works_order_process.wop_id = works_order.wo_current_wop_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process_analysis
ON works_order_process_analysis.wopa_wop_id = works_order_process.wop_id
INNER JOIN variant_detail
ON variant_detail.vad_id = works_order.wo_vad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_total
ON works_order.wo_id = works_order_total.wot_wo_id
LEFT JOIN order_line_item
ON oli_id = wo_oli_id
LEFT JOIN order_header
ON oh_id = oli_oh_id
LEFT JOIN job_number
ON jn_id = wo_jn_id
LEFT JOIN works_order_process_subcontract_analysis
ON wopsa_wop_id = wop_id
LEFT JOIN order_header_detail
ON ohd_oh_id = oh_id
LEFT JOIN customer_detail
ON cd_id = oh_cd_id
WHERE ((cd_ow_account = 'NOTHS')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'EBAY')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = '4008')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'TRUSCA')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1))
AND ((wo_required_datetime <= '2016-12-24 23:59:59'
OR wo_required_datetime IS NULL)
AND (wo_wos_id <> 4)
AND (wo_kit = 0))
```

Comment: In your subquery you are writing group by, so there may be chances that you will get multiple rows. Putting sub query there will not work

Comment: OK, so How do I rectify this? I am unsure so your help would be really appreciated

Comment: To Rectify, first execute the sub query only and see if it is resulting in multiple rows and if so change the group by condition in the sub query based on your required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query, it may helps you

```
SELECT TOP 300000
'' AS alloc_status
,'' AS stock_status
,wo_description
,wo_quantity
,wo_number
,wo_pwos_id
,vad_variant_code
,oh_order_number
,oh_datetime
,ohd_dm_id
,ohd_customer_name
,(SELECT
COUNT(order_line_item.oli_id) AS 'Count'
FROM dbo.order_line_item
INNER JOIN dbo.order_header
ON order_line_item.oli_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_detail
ON order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_setting
ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
WHERE variant_setting.vas_manufactured_variant = 1
and order_header.oh_order_number=ordhead.oh_order_number)
AS CustomLineCount
,vad_description AS vad_description_Condition
,vad_variant_code AS vad_variant_code_Condition
,wo_id AS key_id
FROM works_order
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_analysis
ON works_order_analysis.woa_wo_id = works_order.wo_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process
ON works_order_process.wop_id = works_order.wo_current_wop_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_process_analysis
ON works_order_process_analysis.wopa_wop_id = works_order_process.wop_id
INNER JOIN variant_detail
ON variant_detail.vad_id = works_order.wo_vad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN works_order_total
ON works_order.wo_id = works_order_total.wot_wo_id
LEFT JOIN order_line_item
ON oli_id = wo_oli_id
LEFT JOIN order_header ordhead
ON oh_id = oli_oh_id
LEFT JOIN job_number
ON jn_id = wo_jn_id
LEFT JOIN works_order_process_subcontract_analysis
ON wopsa_wop_id = wop_id
LEFT JOIN order_header_detail
ON ohd_oh_id = oh_id
LEFT JOIN customer_detail
ON cd_id = oh_cd_id
WHERE ((cd_ow_account = 'NOTHS')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'EBAY')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = '4008')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1)
OR (cd_ow_account = 'TRUSCA')
AND (wo_pwos_id = 1))
AND ((wo_required_datetime <= '2016-12-24 23:59:59'
OR wo_required_datetime IS NULL)
AND (wo_wos_id <> 4)
AND (wo_kit = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sub query to this:

```
(SELECT
    COUNT(order_line_item.oli_id) AS 'Count'
FROM dbo.order_line_item
INNER JOIN dbo.order_header
 ON order_line_item.oli_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_detail
 ON order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_setting
 ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
WHERE variant_setting.vas_manufactured_variant = 1
 AND order_header.oh_order_number = OUTER_QUERY_TABLE.SAME_FIELD )
```

I've added this line:

```
AND order_header.oh_order_number = OUTER_QUERY_TABLE.SAME_FIELD
```

You have to make this query correlated , so add the condition to match the record to the outer query . I didn't know which field it is.

You could also optimize your `WHERE` and make it more readable with `IN()` :

```
WHERE wo_pwos_id = 1 
  AND cd_ow_account IN('NOTHS','EBAY','4008','TRUSCA')
  AND (wo_required_datetime <= '2016-12-24 23:59:59' OR wo_required_datetime IS NULL) 
  AND wo_wos_id <> 4
  AND wo_kit = 0
```